# How to capture audio in javascript UWP?

Tags: windows, uwp, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal, uwp-xaml

How to capture audio from microphone in Javascript Universal Windows app?

it have several ways, but all of that are C# solution, like

- [MediaCapture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/basic-photo-video-and-audio-capture-with-mediacapture#add-capability-declarations-to-the-app-manifest)
- [AudioGraph](https://mtaulty.com/2016/02/09/windows-10-uwp-audiographrecording-microphone-to-wav-file/)

Does have a solution for js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty much all the API surface for Win 10 is exposed to JavaScript, you usually just need to fully qualify all the types you want to use and use JavaScript naming conventions with a lowercase letter to start function names.

There's a bunch of information [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/jswinrt/using-the-windows-runtime-in-javascript) about considerations when calling the Windows Runtime from JavaScript (be sure to check the other links on the left too, e.g. [async methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/jswinrt/using-windows-runtime-asynchronous-methods)).

If you look at the [MediaCapture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Media.Capture.MediaCapture) class page directly, they have a small JavaScript snippet around how to initialize it.